# Is it possible to use the verbatim environment in an XY-pic node?

Tags: verbatim, xy-pic

Is it possible to use the **verbatim** environment (i.e. `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`) in an [XY-pic](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~scautis/tools/xypic.pdf) node? If so, please could you provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example)?

---

*Update for those who want example code.*

This (which is based on [the LaTeX Wikibook examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Xy-pic)) renders without errors:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{START}\ar[d] \\
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{\begin{varwidth}{30em}We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim, enter the following at the command prompt:\end{varwidth}} \\
  }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

but this, by contrast

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{START}\ar[d] \\
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{\begin{varwidth}{30em}We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim, enter the following at the command prompt: \begin{verbatim}echo '*.swp' >> .gitignore\end{verbatim}\end{varwidth}} \\
  }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

causes `pdflatex` to halt with the following:

```
<xymatrix
! Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12   }

?
```

Comment: It should be the other way around: *you* provide a possibly non working example showing what you would like to achieve.

Comment: If the question is clear, concise and answerable, why bloat it with a non-working example?

Comment: *What* kind of verbatim do you want to put and *where*? Xy-pic is a big package that provides many features.

Comment: @sampablokuper: Because answers quite often must be tested. If you add a suitable test document to your question you are making life much easier for the people searching for answers.

Comment: @egreg, "What kind of verbatim?" The `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` kind. This must have been obvious enough, as David Carlisle below was apparently able to infer it without difficulty. "Where?" In an XY-pic node, as clearly stated in the question. I don't see how the size of the XY-pic package, nor the fact that it provides other features besides nodes, makes this part of my question unclear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, surely the whole point of asking a question like this is to find out how (best) to do something. I.e. I want a good solution, but *not* necessarily a solution based on a failed (and perhaps quite misguided) attempt of my own. So for this sort of question, I'd rather not risk distracting people by providing such.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @mhp, since when was that a criterion for Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @Jake, the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq) says: "To help people answer your question quickly and precisely, remember to ask clear questions and, *if possible*, to include a small example of code that shows the problem that you want to solve. ... You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." I think my question as originally posed met all these criteria (since IMO the code example decreases the clarity in this case). There's *no* mention in the FAQ of a need to demonstrate original research. Upvotes are nice, but answers matter more.

Comment: @Jake, that said, if you think demonstrating research effort *should* be a criterion for this or any other Stack Exchange site, I guess you could lobby for the relevant FAQ page(s) to be amended accordingly.

Comment: @Jake, yes, I found that, and the phrase "thoroughly searched for an answer" is hyperlinked to http://tex.stackexchange.com/search . I used that and got nothing that appeared to be relevant. (Ditto when googling, btw.) That page says, "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs." Well, I followed that instruction to the letter - assuming it means, "Tell us what you found that was relevant". The point made there is not, AFAICT, "You must demonstrate research effort" but rather, "If you've found some relevant but not quite sufficient information, tell us about it in your question."

Comment: @Jake (Obviously, if a user has already found relevant and sufficient information, then (s)he needn't be asking a question at all.)

Comment: @sampablokuper: You should stop biting the hand that feeds you.

Comment: @RyanReich, I'm not biting anyone. On the contrary, I've been bitten quite hard. My replies have been *only* to defend myself from unjustified criticisms. If a user follows a website's instructions scrupulously, (s)he should not be treated the way I've been treated here in this comment thread.

Comment: Speaking of which, I think this question has received far too many comments and not enough answers. So, to anyone reading this, please give an answer if you have one, instead of another comment!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can never use verbatim commands in a macro argument. You can however always save it in a box and use that box.

```
%in preamble
\newsavebox\mybox
....
% where you want the text
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
....
\foo
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}
\begin{xy....        \usebox{\mybox}......
```

---

Firstly it's worth noting that for the text shown in your edited question verbatim isn't needed at all, a simple font change like `\texttt` can be used as shown in the first fragment below. `verbatim` is needed for multi-line text that included TeX-special characters such as `\` and `{` as in the second example. Which is more or less a direct application of my original answer to your edited question.

[image]

I switched to `article` as my copy of `standalone` can't cope with the display math, I think it's too old.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}



\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{START}\ar[d] \\
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{\begin{varwidth}{30em}We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim, enter the following at the command prompt:
\newline
\texttt{echo '*.swp' >> .gitignore}\end{varwidth}} \\
  }
\end{displaymath}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
multi-line
stuff
with \backslash
and {
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{START}\ar[d] \\
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{\begin{varwidth}{30em}We'll assume that Git is to be used for source control; so as a precaution against accidentally checking in temporary files used by Vim, enter the following at the command prompt:
\usebox\mybox
\end{varwidth}} \\
  }
\end{displaymath}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to turn your snippet into a MWE, but without success. Would you mind expanding it into one? If so, I'll gladly mark this answer as accepted!

Comment: it's 20 years since I used xypic, make a basic document using xypic with VERBATIM HERE and I'll make it verbatim there, that's why the person asking the question should make the MWE the people answering them don't always know as much as you think:-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal example, expanded from David Carlisle's answer above.
Note that `\end{verbatim}` must appear on it own line.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
% echo '*.swp' >> .gitignore
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}

\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{START}\ar[d] \\
    *+[F:<3pt>]\txt{command prompt: \usebox{\mybox}} \\
  }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `lrbox` environment could go inside the `displaymath` environment: I believe this is better style, in this case.